# WillPopScope cannot detect that the Android back button has been pressed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

## Premise・What I want to achieve

I'm planning to use WillPopScope to disable it when the Android back button is pressed.

## Problem・Error message

Enclosing Scaffold in WillPopScope and pressing the Android back button does not execute the function set in WillPopScope.

## Corresponding source code

```
Future<bool> onWillPopScope() async {
    print('on');
    return false;
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return ChangeNotifierProvider<xxxModel>(
  create:(_) => xxxModel(),
  child: Stack(
   children<Widget>[
    WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: onWillPopScope,
     child: Scaffold(
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     )
    ),
    Consumer<xxxModel>(
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ),
   ],
  ),
 );
}
```

## What I tried

I changed the position of WillPopScope, but it doesn't work.

## Supplementary information (FW / tool version, etc.)

・Flutter 1.17.5

・Dart 2.8.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Navigationappbar then try below pprocess,

```
 Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
        return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: Text("NO"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                exit(0);
              },
              child: Text("YES"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ) ??
      false;
    }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   key: _globalKey,
   body: WillPopScope(
      child: _getBody(_currentIndex),//your widget list index wise
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (_globalKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.pop(context); // closes the drawer if opened
          return Future.value(false); // won't exit the app
        } else {
          //only back to o index
          if (_currentIndex == 0) _onBackPressed();
          //return true;
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = 0;
          });
          return false;
          _onBackPressed();
          // return Future.value(true); // exits the app
        }
      },
    ),
   
  );
}
```